# Do Dilos reproduce when they are domesticated?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I tamed a male and a female Dilo. Can they reproduce? If yes, do they have to be "off duty" (not following) for that? Will the offspring be under my command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The only way to get new dinos is currently taming wild ones.
While some (all?) dinos will lay eggs they don't have a purpose besides food yet either
Reproduction/mating is going to be implemented at some point according to the ark devs